# JWT and identifying caller identity

Tags: web-services, authentication, jwt

I have problem understanding how to properly protect services using JWT in terms of identity of a caller. 
I'm trying to build a authentication/authorization service which would be used by multiple other services.
Let's say, for the sake of simplicity, that we have mentioned Auth Service, together with Service A, Service B and Service C.
Service A, B and C are able to verify that tokens were created by the common Auth Service (have public keys).
In the payload of the Token generated for each of the services after Authentication, Authorization rights are listed.

So, something like this:

Agenda:

- Service A needs to access service B. Service C must not access service B.
  Use case:

  1. Service A logs in with the credentials it essentially has for accesing Service B, receiving JWT with payload saying it grants righs for accesing Service B.
  2. Service A makes a request to Service B. Service B validates the token. Service B validates that the Token is intended to be used on itself from the payload.

All good.

Now, what I want to prevent is:

(Step 1 the same as in the use case above)

2. Service C hijacks the JWT created for Service A.
3. Service C access Service B resources.

Basically, the question is, how to prevent that one token, in the end, opens all the doors of the services authed by the common auth service?
Maybe it goes out of the scope of JWT, but somehow, I feel as if, I'm missing some crucial point that could prevent this.

Comment: Always use short-lived tokens and ensure your communication is secured with HTTPS/SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Typically two tokens would be issued to Service A (aka. the "Client") in this use case, one for accessing Service C and one for accessing service B.

Each token would include a so-called "audience" field that specifies who the intended recipient is and it is the recipient's duty to check that field. In a JWT that field would be [`aud`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) and it would contain some identifier that references Service C or B.

Service A would only ever send token B to Service B and token C to Service C. Thus Service C cannot get hold of token B and upon using token C against service B, the audience check performed by service B would make it reject token C.

Comment: But this is not really answering my concern, and my last message in the question might be misleading.

I'm talking about a case of, for example, intentional hijack of a token. 

Is this even a 'viable' possibility that needs to be taken care of?

In what you described, any service could still reuse the token of another service, given it somehow got it into possession.

Comment: when using so-called bearer tokens there's nothing that can be done against it; that would require a different type of token called Proof-of-Possession